Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' - Failed to initialize dependency 'liquibase' of LoadTimeWeaverAware bean 'entityManagerFactory':
I'm in the process of integrating Liquibase into my project. However, I've encountered an issue where an error is triggered immediately upon its addition.
Exceptions Message:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Failed to initialize dependency 'liquibase' of LoadTimeWeaverAware bean 'entityManagerFactory': Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Circular depends-on relationship between 'liquibase' and 'entityManagerFactory'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at sps.SpsBackendApplication.main(SpsBackendApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Circular depends-on relationship between 'liquibase' and 'entityManagerFactory'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 13 common frames omitted


The parent pom.xml
...
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <jib-maven.version>3.4.2</jib-maven.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.13.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.34</lombok.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>backend</module>
        <module>frontend</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
                <version>4.29.2</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>${mockito.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>wf.garnier</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-dex</artifactId>
                <version>${testcontainers.dex.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...

The child pom.xml
....

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>wf.garnier</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers-dex</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
...

I tryed following, but the same error occurs:
@Configuration
public class LiquibaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        // Configure your Liquibase properties here
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml");
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new HikariDataSource();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("liquibase")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.yourpackage");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new HikariDataSource();
    }
}

I've explored various solutions on Stack Overflow in an attempt to resolve my issue, but unfortunately, none have proven effective. As a result, I've decided to bring my question to this forum in hopes of finding the assistance I need.

Remove the LiquibaseConfig and JpaConfig. Restart the application.

@M.Deinum Does not work. I get the same exception

Then you must have some other configuration overriding the one from Spring.

First of all if you are using spring boot and have set database properties in application.properties file than you don't need this in any of class:
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
     return new HikariDataSource();
}

and directly use this like this spring will auto-configure DataSource for you:
@Bean
    @Lazy
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource datasource) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        // Configure your Liquibase properties here
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml");
        liquibase.setDataSource(datasource);
        return liquibase;
    }

And if you want to create your own data source than you can do like this:
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc_url);
    dataSource.setUsername("yourusername");
    dataSource.setPassword("yourpassword");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("your_db_driver");
    return dataSource;
}

Here you are creating datasource tow time with same name you have to give method different name for method like :
DataSource primaryDataSource() {...}
DataSource secondaryDataSource() {...}


I understand the situation. The challenge we're facing is figuring out a solution for the circular dependency between 'liquibase' and 'entityManagerFactory'.
